# Run if statement checker every time when the user click on the button

Tags: javascript, jquery

for example i have a p tag and i have a javascript function to increase it's value by 10 every time when a user click on a button.

HTML:

```
    <p id="test">0</p>
   <button id="trigger">test</button>
```

Jquery:

```
     var empty;
    $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#trigger").click(function(){
                empty = $("#test").html()+10;
                $("#test").html(empty);
               console.log($("#test").html());

              }
        })
})
```

This should update the p tag's number but the console.log always display 0 still.
is there any eorror inside? The below is just an example, i just want to know how to make a  if statement run everytime when a user click on a specify button.

Comment: you need to convert it to integer first. try using `parseInt($("#test").text())`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/t2ubabrd/

Comment: Are you sure the console log is displaying 0?  It _should_ be `010`, `01010`, `0101010` etc?

Comment: Im surprised it didn't do a simple string concat. so outputted `010`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/oxdykdpw/1/ - you have a syntax error - extra `}` after `console.log($("#test").html());`

Comment: or https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/oxdykdpw/2/

Comment: try using empty = Number($("#test").html())+10;

Answer (score 1):

You should use parseInt to convert string to integer

> The parseInt() function parses a string argument and returns an
>   integer of the specified radix (the base in mathematical numeral
>   systems).

[Read More](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

```js
var empty;
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#trigger").click(function() {
    empty = parseInt($("#test").html()) + 10;
    $("#test").html(empty);
    console.log($("#test").html());

  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="test">0</p>
<button id="trigger">test</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are adding string to number which results in string only, user `parseInt()` to covert text into number then do addition, as shown below

Note: your code has one extra `}` that need to be removed

```js
var empty;
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#trigger").click(function(){
    empty = parseInt($("#test").html()) + 10;
    $("#test").html(empty);
    console.log($("#test").html());
   //remove extra } from here
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="test">0</p>
<button id="trigger">test</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

convert to int  parseInt($("#test").html()) and than do 10 +